# What is the best way to keep local state in a node in Bonobo-etl?

Tags: python-3.x, bonobo-etl

If I have an input queue with 20 numbers, how can I get e.g. the sum of all numbers? So far this is what I came up with:

```
import bonobo as bb
from bonobo.config import Configurable, ContextProcessor
from bonobo.util import ValueHolder

def extract_nums():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

class TransformNumber(Configurable):
    @ContextProcessor
    def total(self, context):
        yield ValueHolder({'extract':0,'transform':0})

    def __call__(self, total, num, **kwargs):
        total['extract']+=num
        transform_num = num * 10
        total['transform']+=transform_num
        if num==3: # Final number
            print("TOTALS:",total.get())
        yield transform_num

graph = bb.Graph()
graph.add_chain(
    extract_nums,
    TransformNumber(),
    bb.PrettyPrinter()
)
```

It is ok to do it like this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different available options to keep local state in a Bonobo ETL node.

It's ok to do it like you did (although I think it's hard to read), I tend to prefer to use closures which I think are more readable (but I agree, that's debatable):

```
import bonobo


def CumSum():
    total = 0

    def cum_sum(x):
        nonlocal total
        total += x
        yield x, total

    return cum_sum


def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.get_cursor() >> range(100) >> CumSum() >> print

    return graph


# The __main__ block actually execute the graph.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = bonobo.get_argument_parser()
    with bonobo.parse_args(parser) as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph(**options))
```

A few examples are available in the bonobo source code, please look in https://github.com/python-bonobo/bonobo/blob/develop/bonobo/nodes/basics.py (and there are examples written in different styles).

Note that I'm using the Bonobo 0.7 (incoming) syntax here to build the graph, but the same thing can be used with current stable version (0.6) by replacing ">>" operators by add_chain calls.